# time for m.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, user-experience

Is it not time to implement a mobile version of the site?

pros:

- browsing experience
- greater availability
- more traffic

cons:

- txtspeak answers
- fewer ad impressions

Comment: -fewer ad impressions, -txtspeak answers

Comment: @Shog9, the URL looks a lot like `meta.stackoverflow.com`. Oh...

Comment: @Pop: roflz wut

Comment: @Simon Brown definetly the same request, definetly not a duplicate. + I'm trying to create a list to give a better overview
@Shog9 added

Answer (score 5):

Two mobile projects are already out there using the Stack API (links are to StackApps project page):

- [Six to Eight](https://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client-now-in-the-app-store) (Native iPhone client app)
- [StackMobile](https://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone) (Mobile-optimized web app)

Both use the Stack API, which is currently read-only, so no asking/answering/voting is currently possible.

Yes, I'd support a full mobile app as you suggest, but hopefully these will tide you over.